# Synching GSheet with GCalendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, spreadsheet

I successfully linked my GSheet to GCalendar but now I have some open questions:

1. How can I avoid that multiple Calendar events are created when running the AppsScript Code?[the Calendar Event bla1 should only be once in my calendar. But everytime I run the code in the Apps Script GCalendar keeps adding more bla1 events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO15V.png)
2. If I would update an event (e.g. the start time changed), How can it be changed in my Calendar automatically?
3. How could I automatically add attendees to the events and have the event send out invites?

Here is the Apps Script code so far:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TtjU.png)

And here is the Spreadsheet:
[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfu99.png)

Comment: Pease read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. Never include code in an image. It also helps if you share the `sheet` with `viewer` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*You can use the method [addGuest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addguestemail) to add attendees to an [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event)*.

### Code

I have written a small sample of code that creates a new event and add two attendees to it:

```
function createEvent() {
 
  var title = 'test event'
  var start = new Date('April 28, 2021 13:00:00 -0500');
  var end = new Date('April 28, 2021 17:00:00 -0500');
  var guest1 = 'mail1@example.com'
  var guest2 = 'mail2@example.com'

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('primary')
  var event = calendar.createEvent(title, start, end)

  event.addGuest(guest1)
  event.addGuest(guest2)
   
}
```

If you already have an `event` created and want to add attendees, you must first get it with a `getEvent` *(getEventsById, getEventSeriesById, getEvents, getEventsForDay)* method within the desired [calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar):

### References

- [Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar)
- [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event)
- [CalendarEvent: addGuest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addguestemail)